# Zoho Shared Form Custom HTML

Tags: javascript, cors, zoho

I would like to know if anyone can help me with a question using Zoho Custom HTML form.

Currently zoho offers the option to add the form through an iframe, however I cannot use the iframe in this application. Then I have the option to add the custom form HTML directly to our page.

The problem is that I'm trying to submit the form via AJAX, but I'm getting CORS error message.

Has anyone used zoho form, and knows how I can make this request and receive data from zoho?

I am getting this error.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://forms.zohopublic...t' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Is it because I'm running the script on my local machine, when it goes up to the server it will work?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#submit-button").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log($("#form-id").serialize());
                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "https://forms.zohopublic.com/teste/form/Bemvindo/formperma/BBRMrFc6LR/htmlRecords/submit'",
                data: $("#form-id").serialize(),
                success: function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
        });

 
    });
    </script>

    <form action='https://forms.zohopublic.com/teste/form/Bemvindo/formperma/BBRMrFc6LR/htmlRecords/submit' name='form' method='POST'>
         <label>First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" maxlength="255" name="name" placeholder="" />
          <label>Emai</label>
        <input type="text" maxlength="255" name="email" placeholder="" />
</form>
```